# two applications used in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have two app (webapp and mysql)
In overlay of swarm(like https://blog.docker.com/2015/11/docker-multi-host-networking-ga/), i use docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: mywebapp
    ports:
     - "8088:8080"
    environment:
     - "constraint:node==swl-demo0"
    networks:
     - mfnw
    depends_on:
     - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.10
    command: mysql -uroot -proot < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=msgflow
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - "constraint:node==swl-demo1"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-config/:/etc/mysql/conf.d:ro
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - /srv/docker/msgflow/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - mfnw
    container_name: mysql

networks:
  mfnw:
```

and i create overlay named mfnw
and my webapp use "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/msgflow?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8" to connect mysql.
but it throwd the error "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up."

when i use one host, it work. it only happen on two host, i don't why?

forgive my English!

Comment: Do you have a discovery service like consul configured?

Comment: yes, it used consul.